# Sinon callCount shows different results when spied function uses setTimeout with a wrapped function vs unwrapped

Tags: javascript, testing, settimeout, sinon

### This is the test:

```
describe('blinkyDancer', function() {
  const { expect } = chai;
  let blinkyDancer;
  let clock;
  let timeBetweenSteps = 100;

  beforeEach(function() {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    blinkyDancer = makeBlinkyDancer(10, 20, timeBetweenSteps);
  });

  describe('dance', function() {
    it('should call step at least once per second', function() {
      sinon.spy(blinkyDancer, 'step');
      expect(blinkyDancer.step.callCount).to.be.equal(0);
      // Depending on your solution, you may need an extra tick
      // If it does, try and refactor your solution to not
      // clock.tick(timeBetweenSteps);
      clock.tick(timeBetweenSteps);

      expect(blinkyDancer.step.callCount).to.be.equal(1);

      clock.tick(timeBetweenSteps);
      expect(blinkyDancer.step.callCount).to.be.equal(2);
    });
  });
});
```

---

### This is the code being tested:

```
const makeDancer = function(top, left, timeBetweenSteps) {
  const dancer = {};

  dancer.$node = $('<span class="dancer"></span>');
 
  dancer.step = function() {
    // This version passes with only one initial tick in 
    // the code which is the expected outcome
    setTimeout(() => dancer.step(), timeBetweenSteps);
    
    // This version fails with only one initial tick in 
    // the code but passes if given two initial ticks
    // setTimeout(dancer.step, timeBetweenSteps);
  };

  dancer.setPosition = function(top, left) {
    const styleSettings = {
      top: top,
      left: left
    };
    dancer.$node.css(styleSettings);
  };
  
  dancer.setPosition(top, left);

  dancer.step();

  return dancer;
};

const makeBlinkyDancer = function(top, left, timeBetweenSteps) {
  const blinkyDancer = makeDancer(top, left, timeBetweenSteps);

  const oldStep = blinkyDancer.step;

  blinkyDancer.step = function() {
    oldStep();
    blinkyDancer.$node.toggle();
  };

  return blinkyDancer;
};
```

---

### The problem:

If the SetTimeout callback is just the step function, `setTimeout(dancer.step, timeBetweenSteps)`, the test fails unless an extra tick of `clock.tick(timeBetweenSteps)` is given. On the other hand, if you wrap the step function and pass the wrapper to the callback, `setTimeout(() => dancer.step(), timeBetweenSteps)`, then the test passes just fine with only 1 initial tick.

---

### My question:

Why does having a wrapped function make the test pass? I have already figured out multiple ways to make the test pass that I can sort of imagine an explanation for why they pass, but I can't come up with anything great for this one. The only leads I have are that Sinon replaces the setTimeout function with a synchronous version in testing environments, so maybe that messed with the functionality.